# Force portrait or landscape mode in android depending on screen size

Tags: android, landscape, mode, portrait

I've been doing some research over the last few hours, as well as some trial and error, however I am not able to find a fully working solution for this problem. I would simply like to force my android application to stay in portrait mode unless the screen size is big enough (tablet), which then will force the app to be in landscape mode.

What I've tried so far:

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

As well as:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

in my onCreate and onResume.

The first example does work somewhat, however this will not allow me to check screen size and force landscape mode if it is a tablet. Furthermore, if I'm holding my phone in landscape mode while an asynctask is executing, the app will go into landscape mode after the task is done, and then I am allowed to switch between portrait and landscape again as long as I stay in the same activity.

So, I am not sure how the proper way to handle this is? If I go with the second example (which with a bit more of code allows me to check screen size, and then choose layout depending on the size) does work as long as I am in the activity. However if I'm holding my phone in landscape mode while starting the activity everything crashes (so seems like the code isn't effective in the beginning).

Any suggestions that may work *completely* without any "bugs", which is the case right now would be highly appreciated!

Comment: "I would simply like to force my android application to stay in portrait mode unless the screen size is big enough (tablet), which then will force the app to be in landscape mode." -- why do you think that your users will want this?

Comment: You do make a valid point, and this is something I have been thinking about back and forth. However, I think the app looks a lot better in portrait on phones, and it there is another design for landscape mode which is made for bigger screens. Therefore it looks a bit strange to be in landscape on a smaller screen. That's the main reason. It is true that I could let the user decide what mode he wants to be in, however since I have seen many apps being able to implement this and since I've spent some time on it, I'm a bit curious just how to get it done, so I can decide after having tried.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is very late, but here is my answer in case it may help someone else.

I went the programmatic route and didn't encounter any problems when starting the app while in the landscape or portrait positions.

Ignore the manifest options. Use setRequestedOrientation() in onCreate() as you mention. Do a check for screen size, for instance:

```
private boolean screenIsLarge()
{
    int screenMask = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout;
    if ( ( screenMask & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
        return true;
    }

    if ( (screenMask & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
            Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE) {
                return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

You can modify this to include other screen sizes listed in `Configuration`. Based on this result you can choose whether to set the screen to landscape.

```
if( screenIsLarge() )
{
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
```